# App not available in Google Play by search request

Tags: android, google-play

I published my android app in google play store 24h ago. Everything seems to work regular and the app is available in the store by using the direct link "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.myappid".

But it is not available by using the Google Store search field. And the app is not part of "other apps of the developer".

What can I do?

Comment: Wait or contact Google.

Comment: I tried to contact google, but I didn't find an email address or contact form :-(

Comment: Go to the developer console and then to "Contact Support" under "Need Help". It has an option for visibility issues.

Answer (score 4):

It may take more than 24 hours to get listed in search.  They cache heavily, and don't do instant crawling.

To boost your search ranking, you should focus on getting inbound links to your app, and social interaction.

Get a lot of +1s on Google+ for your app, and see if you can get bloggers talking.

Google places a lot of weight on social activity.  The days of showing in search results only based on the title and description of your app are long gone unfortunately.

Comment: thx for your answer, but it seems so be an known google bug at the moment :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found that google knows that problem:

"We're currently aware of an issue causing some developers to not appear correctly in Google Play search. This is also effecting the Developers Apps page, which shows all apps by a specific developer. We appreciate your patience while we work on a fix for these issues."

:-( Hopefully they are going to fix it soon